# How to parse particular column in json file into R?

Tags: r

I have my json column as:

```
list(type=c("commercial_permit","Fitness_certificate","insurance","pollution")
```

I am trying to separate out the columns from this but not getting the correct output.

I have 1 column named documents compliance status.It is divided into different subparts as a list with columns and corresponding data values. So i am trying to make that list into different columns.

snapshot of data in R

documentsComplianceStatus
1                              Commercial_Permit, Fitness_Certificate, Insurance, Pollution, Road_tax, Registration, EHS, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.3, PASSED, 21-May-2017, 01-Jul-2017, 01-May-2018, 10-Oct-2017, 31-Jul-2017, 07-May-2013, NA, Non-Compliant, Non-Compliant, Non-Compliant, Non-Compliant, Non-Compliant, Non-Compliant, Compliant, AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE, NOT_REQUIRED, NOT AVAILABLE, NOT AVAILABLE, NOT AVAILABLE, NOT AVAILABLE, NOT AVAILABLE, NOT AVAILABLE,

I have tried by rbind but couldn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your JSON is as below:

```
$type
[1] "commercial_permit"   "Fitness_certificate" "insurance"           "pollution"
```

You can simply make this into columns by piping it into a data frame from the `tidyverse` package. I have made another list with "2" columns.

```
list(
type=c("commercial_permit","Fitness_certificate","insurance","pollution"),
type_2=c("commercial_permit_2","Fitness_certificate_2","insurance_2","pollution_2")
) %>% 
as.data.frame()


                 type                type_2
1   commercial_permit   commercial_permit_2
2 Fitness_certificate Fitness_certificate_2
3           insurance           insurance_2
4           pollution           pollution_2
```

Unsure if this what your asking. Please provide a reproducible example.